# firebase-queue: Multiple workers not running correctly?

Tags: node.js, queue, firebase

I'm pretty new to Node.js, though I've been writing javascript for years. I'm more than open to any node advice for best-practices that I'm not following, or other rethinks. That said:

I'm building a system in which a user creates a reservation, and simultaneously submits a task for my firebase-queue to pick up. This queue has multiple specs associated with it. In turn, it's supposed to:

1. check availability, and in response confirm/throw an alert on the reservation and update the firebase data accordingly.
2. Update the users reservations, which is an index of reservation object keys, and removing any redundant ones.
3. Use node-schedule to create dated functions to send notifications about the pending expiration of their reservation.

However, when I run my script, only one of the firebase-queues that I instantiate runs. I can look in the dashboard and see that the progress is at 100, the _state is the new finished_state (which is the next spec's start_state), but that next queue won't pick up the task and process it.

If I quit my script and rerun it, that next queue will work fine. And then the queue after that won't work, until I repeat the act of quitting and rerunning the script. I can continue this until the entire task sequence completes, so I don't think the specs or the code being executed itself are blocking. I don't see any error states spring up, anyway.

From the documentation it looks like I should be able to write the script this way, with multiple calls to 'new Queue(queueRef, options, function(data, progress, resolve, reject)...' and they'll just run each task as I set them in their options (all of which are basically:

```
var options = {
  'specId': 'process_reservation',
  'numWorkers': 5,
  'sanitize': true,
  'suppressStack': false
};
```

but, nope. I guess I can spawn child-processes for each of the queue instances, but I'm not sure if that's an extreme reaction to the issues I'm seeing, and I'm not sure if it would complicate the node structure in terms of shared module exports. Also, I'm not sure if it'll start eating into my concurrent connection count.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, the documentation seems to be inconsistent on whether the 'ref' for the Queue instantiations should point to 'queue' or 'queue/tasks' on Firebase. I've been using 'queue' across the board.

Comment: What version of node / io.js are you running? I just tested this on node v0.10.40 and v0.12.7 with a simple queue and it did chain as expected. The best way to allow anyone to help further would be by creating an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, you might get more information by turning on debug logging in `winston` by first requiring the module, and then calling: `winston.level = 'debug';`

Comment: @ChrisRaynor - I'm using node v012.7. When I was having problems I made sure I updated everything. I'll try winston. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisRaynor Installed winston in debug mode (although it wasn't much help until I realized I was using firebase-queue 1.2.0, and updating to 1.2.1 made it all much more verbose.) Still seeing the issue, though. On startup each queue worker reports listening, but when one step completes the next listener doesn't actually pick it up. Editing the spec in firebase dashboard 'wakes them up' (I discovered this when I changed the retries value for one of the specs). Still plugging away at getting a mvce together.

Comment: This still an issue? Solved something similar recently...